# How could you check if a window popup exists using Selenium w/ C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently writing a program that has a 'Submit' button that displays a list of providers within a certain area. However, a separate screen may popup if the provider has offices in more than one location (ie. different states, different offices around the same city, etc). If he's located in a single area, a dropdown occurs instead without the need to use window handling for the popup.

So far, my code fails 50% of the time since half of the providers operate in only one location and consequently, no popup appears. While it passes the other 50% since a popup appears and the code continues with no further issues.

My question is, how can I tell Selenium to search for a separate screen once I click the 'Submit' button. And if it doesn't appear, to continue on instead?

My code so far:

```
        string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
        string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(BtnAccept);

        if(popupWindowHandle != currentHandle)
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);
            BtnSelectPopUpProvider.Click();
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandle);
        }
```

Comment: What is the failure message the 50% of the time that it fails?

Comment: I get a timeout exception. The next objective after finding a provider without a popup is click a button labeled 'Add New Provider'.

Comment: Yes but what line of code times out. Please add the exception text.

Comment: I'm confused here. Why is `string popupWindowHandle` getting  compared to `driver.CurrentWindowHandle`? How does `finder.Click(BtnAccept);` return a valid window handle string? There seem to be a few essential parts of your code missing from this sample.

Comment: BtnAccept is from a method from the POM on my work project solution, hence why I didn't add it in. However, I think a major issue is with the if statement parameters

Comment: Doesn't seem like you posted enough of the markup or code to troubleshoot, but I think you should check "numberOfwindowsToBe" after clicking: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfwindowsToBe-int-

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will be of any help, but what about using this construction ?

```
string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
try
{
    string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(BtnAccept);
    if (popupWindowHandle != currentHandle)
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);
        BtnSelectPopUpProvider.Click();
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandle);
    }
}
catch { }
```

On timeout the code below the try will continue to execute.